# Quotient theorem for tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Can somebody please explain to me how the following statement is true?

> The [Riemann curvature tensor $R^c_{dab}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) is given by the Ricci identity $$(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)V^c\equiv R^c_{dab}V^d$$ where $\nabla_a$ denotes the covariant derivative. It is linear in $V^c$, hence may be shown by the Quotient theorem to be a tensor.

Now, I can see that the $R^c_{dab}$ is a tensor by construction -- based on the LHS of the Ricci identity. However, I don't understand how the linearity in $V^d$ comes to play.

---

Also, it is  given that for covectors, the Ricci identity takes the form

> $$(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)V_c\equiv -R^d_{cab}V_d$$

How does this follow from the Ricci identity for (contravariant) vectors?

If I write $$(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)V_c=(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)(g_{cd}V^d)$$ and in GR, the Levi-Civita connection has that the metric is covariantly constant, we have 
$$(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)(g_{cd}V^d)=g_{cd}(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)V^d\\=g_{cd}R^d_{eab}V^e=R_{ceab}V^e=R^d_{cab}V_d$$ 
 Where has my minus sign gone?

I have read that you can  the Ricci identity for covectors by arguing using the fact that the Levi-Civita connection is symmetric, but I don't know how they mean.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In this context, "symmetric" = "torsion-free" (the latter is better to use).

Comment: @YuriVyatkin: Indeed.

Comment: $R_{ceab}=-R_{ecab}$ so the last step of your calculation should be $R_{ceab}V^e=-R_{ecab}V^e=-R^d_{cab}V_d$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the linearity is really easy:
$$
(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)(f\,V^c) = f (\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)V^c
$$
because the connection is assumed to be torsion free:
$$
(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)f=0
$$
 (otherwise your "Ricci identity" won't work).

A slick way of doing this is to observe that the operator $(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)$ satisfies the product rule.

With regards to the minus sign, the problem is that the order of indices in the curvature tensor is important. It is better to write
$$
(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)V^c = R_{a b}{}^c{}_d V^d
$$
and then
$$
\begin{align}
(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)V_c
& = (\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)(g_{cd}V^d) \\
&= g_{cd}(\nabla_a\nabla_b-\nabla_b\nabla_a)V^d\\
& =g_{cd} R_{a b}{}^d{}_e V^e \\
&= R_{a b d e} V^e = - R_{a b e d} V^e =  -  R_{a b}{}^c{}_d  V_c
\end{align}
$$

(I have learned all this from R. Wald's "General relativity")

Comment: Thank you very very much, Yuri! (Extra thanks for the reference -- I have been looking for a good reference book.) :)